# Swift - UITextField resets but UILabel doesn't

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikit, uilabel

I've done plenty of searching but am not finding the answer to my question.

My two `UITextFields` fields are resetting using the clear function. The `UILabel` retains the original value from the printWatts function, doesn't clear. Would appreciate any advice to resolve this small issue as I learn Swift. Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var inputFeet: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputWatts: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultsLabel: UILabel!

    var stripFeet = ""
    var wattValue = ""
    var totalWatts : Float = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func submitButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        calculateWatts()
    }

    @IBAction func clearButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        clear()
    }

    func calculateWatts() {
        if let stripFeet = inputFeet.text,
            wattValue = inputWatts.text,
            fstripFeet = Float(stripFeet),
            fwattValue = Float(wattValue){
                totalWatts = fstripFeet * fwattValue
        }
        printWatts()
    }

    func printWatts() {
        let formatWatts = String(format: "%0.2f", totalWatts)
        resultsLabel.text = "Total watts: \(formatWatts)"
    }

    func clear(){
        inputFeet.text = ""
        inputWatts.text = ""
        self.resultsLabel.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the connections of your buttons?

Comment: That was it! I somehow had the submit and clear actions wired up to my submit button. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Eendje for suggesting that I check my connections. I had the submit and clear actions both connected to my submit button. Option drag is too convenient. All good now.